# MySQL Inner join and sum two columns

Tags: mysql, sum, inner-join

I have the following tables

**TABLE: appointments**

```
ID | PRICE | PAID
48 |  100  | 180
```

**TABLE: appointments_products**

```
ID | APPOINTMENT_ID | PRODUCT_ID | TOTAL
10 |       48       |      1     | 30
11 |       48       |      9     | 30
12 |       48       |      6     | 30
```

I Would like to somehow run a MySQL query that will:

a) join the two tables, SUM the "TOTAL" of appointments_products for each appointment_id and if the "PAID" is not equal of the PRICE (from appointments table) + TOTAL (from appointments_products table) then to show it.

This is what I have done so far:

```
select a.*, b.appointment_id as AppId, b.total as ProdTotal 
from appointments a 
INNER JOIN appointments_products b ON a.id = b.appointment_id
```

But this query does not sum the total for each appointment_id

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.ID,a.PRICE,a.PAID,a.id as AppId,
       sum(b.total) as ProdTotal 
from appointments a 
INNER JOIN appointments_products b ON a.id = b.appointment_id
group by a.ID,a.PRICE,a.PAID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use where to check if price is equal to paid and the use group by to group with appointment_id.

Answer (score 0):

select b.Appointment_Id, a.price, a.PAID, a.id, sum(b.total) AS TotalProd FROM appointments_products AS b inner join appointments as a On Appointment_Id = a.Id  group by Appointment_Id,  a.Price , a.PAID , a.id HAVING a.PAID != (a.Price + sum(b.Total))